# Email validation, consecutive periods

Tags: regex

I am using `^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.\']+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$` to validate emails. But this regex is not validating consecutive periods. What can I change to accept consecutive periods?

Comment: Please provide examples of what is and isn't validating. The regex you have will validate for `test..test@test.com`. Just as a side note, be aware that you are not supporting all email addresses with that regex. If you want to truly validate emails you need to reference [RFC 822](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc822#section-6.1) and [RFC 5322](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5322).

Comment: Your regex matches `-.-.-.-.@0.1.2.aa`, not sure it's a valid address. But it doesn't match `me@localhost` that is valid.

Comment: Worse, it will reject any localpart containing `+*%=&$` and a number of other valid characters. `+` in particular is aggravating because addresses with a plus in them are a common feature for extending mailbox names -- for example, on servers which support this extension, if you own `you@example.com`, you could create a dedicated address `you+stackoverflow@example.com` without setting up a separate physical mailbox.